# Autosum with generated fields JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a bit stuck with javascript again. Basically when you click a button a new row of fields will appear, giving them a new name just a different number.

I now need these fields to be able to auto sum by themself, i can do this with the first row I just don't know how to do them with the new generated ones.

The Javascript code:

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      var i=2;
      function addRow()
{
      var tbl = document.getElementById('customersAdd');
      var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
      var iteration = lastRow - 1;
      var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);

      var firstCell = row.insertCell(0);
      var el = document.createElement('input');
      el.placeholder = 'Quantity';
      el.type = 'text';
      el.name = 'quantity' + i;
      el.id = 'quantity' + i;
      firstCell.appendChild(el);

      var secondCell = row.insertCell(1);
      var el2 = document.createElement('input');
      el2.placeholder = 'Description';
      el2.type = 'text';
      el2.name = 'description' + i;
      el2.id = 'description' + i;
      secondCell.appendChild(el2);

      var thirdCell = row.insertCell(2);
      var el3 = document.createElement('input');
      el3.placeholder = 'Rate';
      el3.type = 'text';
      el3.name = 'rate' + i;
      el3.id = 'rate' + i;
      thirdCell.appendChild(el3);

      var forthCell = row.insertCell(3);
      var el4 = document.createElement('input');
      el4.placeholder = 'Amount';
      el4.type = 'text';
      el4.name = 'amount' + i;
      el4.id = 'amount' + i;
            forthCell.appendChild(el4);
     // alert(i);
      i++;

    //  alert(i);
}
function startCalc(){
  interval = setInterval("calc()",1);
}
function calc(){
    one = document.main.quantity1.value;
  two = document.main.rate1.value; 
  document.main.amount1.value = (one * 1) * (two * 1);

}
function stopCalc(){
  clearInterval(interval);
}
</script>
```

The HTML code:

```
<form action="submit.php" name="main" method="post">
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" align="center" width="50%" class="horiz" id="customersAdd">
   <tr>

     <td align="center"><br/>
     <input class="text" style="width:100%" type="button" align="middle"value="Add Aditional Row" onClick="addRow()" /></td>
   </tr>
    <tr align="center">

     <td>
       <br />
       <input placeholder="Quantity" type="text" name="quantity1" id="quantity1" onFocus="startCalc();" onBlur="stopCalc();" />
       <br /></td>
     <td>
       <br />
       <input placeholder="Description" type="text" name="description1" id="description1"/>
       <br /></td>
     <td>
       <br />
       <input placeholder="Rate" type="text" name="rate1" id="rate1" onFocus="startCalc();" onBlur="stopCalc();"/>
       <br /></td>
     <td>
       <br />
       <input placeholder="Amount" type="text" name="amount1" id="amount1" onBlur="stopCalc();" onFocus="startCalc();" readonly="true" />
       <br /></td>
</tr>

 </table></form>
```

To make things easier for anyone who could help me I have made this in JSBin to see it easier of what i want to do. Any suggestions are appreciated.

http://jsbin.com/atabaz/1/edit

Thanks

Comment: The code is very redundant. Try to make better use of the generic DOM capabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I managed to find a way on how to do this myself, if anyone is interested take a look at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/2sYgE/

```
    var currentItem = 1;

$('#customersAdd').on('keyup', '.quantity, .rate, .amount', calculateRow);

$('#addnew').click(function() {
    currentItem++;

    $('#customersAdd').append('<tr><td><input placeholder="Quantity" type="text" name="quantity' + currentItem +'" id="quantity' + currentItem +'" class="qty form-input-rate" /></td><td><input placeholder="Description" type="text" name="description' + currentItem +'" id="description' + currentItem +'" class="form-input-rate"/></td><td><input placeholder="Rate" type="text" name="rate' + currentItem +'" id="rate' + currentItem +'" class="rate form-input-rate"/></td><td><input placeholder="Amount" type="text" name="amount' + currentItem +'" id="amount' + currentItem +'" class="cal form-input-rate"/></td></tr>'
    );
});

function calculateSum() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(".cal").each(function () {
        if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }
    });

}

function calculateRow() {
    var cost = 0;
    var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var qty = parseFloat($row.find('.qty').val());

    // changed the following line to only look within the current row
    var rate = parseFloat($row.find('.rate').val());

    cost = qty * rate;

    if (isNaN(cost)) {
        $row.find('.cal').val("0");
    } else {
        $row.find('.cal').val(cost);
    }
    calculateSum();
}
```

Comment: `if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) { sum += parseFloat(this.value);}` can be just `sum += parseFloat(this.value) || 0`. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Polling for changes is a very inefficient and error–prone way to do form updates. Listening for change events is a better way to go as it uses fewer resources and waits until the user has finished updating the control before doing anything. There is also an input event that can be used, but it's not suitable here as it will update the form as the user enters values. Much better to wait for the user to finish entering values, then do the update.

I've re–factored your code below, it's not ready for production but it should give you some idea of how to go about it. Table rows are cloned as it's much faster than creating all the elements from scratch. Then names are modified, though this isn't really necessary. There is no need for ID attributes.

Cloning only works reliably here if inline listeners are used on the form controls. If the initial listeners are dynamically attached, you'll have to add them each time a row is added as listeners added using *addEventListener* are not cloned.

I haven't included any input validation, if the user puts in junk, they get junk back. You should validate input to check that appropriate values are being entered, and also format the displayed values for presentation.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function addRow(element) {
      var form = element.form;
      var table = form.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
      var tbody = table.tBodies[0];
      var num = tbody.rows.length - 1;
      var row = table.rows[1].cloneNode(true);
      var input, inputs = row.getElementsByTagName('input')

      // Update input names
      for (var i=0, iLen=inputs.length; i<iLen; i++) {
        input = inputs[i];
        input.name = input.name.replace(/\d+$/,num);
        input.value = '';
      }
      tbody.insertBefore(row, tbody.rows[tbody.rows.length - 1]);
  }

  function updateRow(element) {
    var form = element.form;
    var num = element.name.replace(/^\D+/,'');
    var value = form['quantity' + num].value * form['rate' + num].value;
    form['amount' + num].value =  (value == 0)? '' : value;
    updateTotal(form);
  }

  function updateTotal(form) {
    var elements = form.elements;
    var name = /^amount/;
    var total = 0;
    var value;

    for (var i=0, iLen=elements.length; i<iLen; i++) {
      if (name.test(elements[i].name)) {
        total += parseFloat(elements[i].value);
      }
    }
    form.total.value = total;
  }
</script>

<form action="submit.php" name="main" method="post">
  <table style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" align="center"
   width="50%" class="horiz" id="customersAdd">
    <tr>
      <td><br>
        <input class="text" style="width:100%" type="button" 
         align="middle"value="Add Aditional Row" onclick="addRow(this)">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input placeholder="Quantity" name="quantity1" onblur="updateRow(this);">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input placeholder="Description" type="text" name="description1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input placeholder="Rate" name="rate1" onchange="updateRow(this);">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input placeholder="Amount" name="amount1" readonly>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" style="text-align: right">Total&nbsp;
      <td><input name="total" readonly>
    </tr>
  </table>
    <input type="reset">
</form>
```